# How to replace comma with character in Unix bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix, sunos

I have the below string:

`"BBBB,AAAA"` seperated with `comma`. I need to append `.done` with each value of the string.

When i try below. It doesnot work. I try to replace `,` with `.done` but its doesnot work. Also i need the `.done` at the end of both `AAAA` and `BBBB`

```
-bash-3.2$ echo "AAAA,BBBB" |tr "," ".done" 
 AAAA.BBBB
```

Expected Output:

```
AAAA.done  BBBB.done
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

After @Ravindra Suggestion, i modified it little bit and its working fine but the problem now is to trim the spaces.

```
-bash-3.2$ echo "AAAA,BBBB ,CCC, DDD" | sed 's/,/.done /g;s/$/.done/'
 AAAA.done BBBB .done  CCC.done  DDD.done
               ^  
               getting space here
```

OS name: SunOS

Comment: Next time it might be nice to state that "Does Not Work" means that only the comma was being replaced by the 1st character in ".done" i.e  the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
val="AAAA,BBBB"
echo "$val" | sed 's/,/.done /;s/$/.done/'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
AAAA.done BBBB.done
```

***EDIT:***

```
awk -v val="$val" 'BEGIN{gsub(/,| ,/,".done ",val);sub(/$/,".done",val);print val}'
```

***EDIT2:***

```
awk -v val="$val" 'BEGIN{gsub(/,| ,/,".done ",val);sub(/$/,".done",val);print val}'
AAA.done  BBB.done  CCC.done DDD.done
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnot work incase val='AAA,BBB,CCC". I mean when the number of parameters are increased. It doesnot work. Can you please suggest

Comment: @XING, check my edit solution now and let me know on same then. It should handle multiple `,` in it too, let me know if this works well for you?

Comment: One more thing ..incase the string is like `"AAA, BBB  , CCC  ,DDD"` , here in this case the result is `AAA.done  BBB .done  CCC .done`. i mean the space between the `BBB .done` should b removed as well

Comment: @XING, I have edited my solution now, check and let me know then?

Comment: Getting syntax error `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1` . can you please check

Comment: @XING, on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk

Comment: @XING, always add your OS name what you are using so that we could add solution as per that itself.

Comment: I mean i didnot your `awk` command rather used the previous command. But i landed up another problem. Please see if you could help. I would surely accept the answer if it work for me..

Comment: @XING, if you keep saying you have problems without giving description, I am afraid then no one could help you either, I think I have given lot of effort here but you didn't bother to provide all information in single comment or post, I leave up to you on providing information. I would suggest better to open a new thread with FULL description, thanks and keep learning !!

Comment: What else information you need. I already edited my question and posted OS name. Please see edit part of my question. Let me know if you dont understand anything.

Comment: `awk` is somhow not working with me. Cannot i do it with some simpler way as i did ?

Comment: @XING, my EDIT code was providing the required output, please see mine EDIT2 seems it is providing correct output as per your need, check and let me know then.

Comment: @XING, also mentioned in comment too, change awk to on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk

Comment: Thanks now its working. But is there a way to avoid `awk` ?